# How to calculate the collector resistor of this emitter circuit?

Tags: transistors, bjt, common-emitter

My supply voltage is +10 V, collector current at my bias point is 5 mA, base current is 28.8 uA, amplification is 173.3.

[image]

I already calculated the base resistor to be $$R_1=\frac{V_{CC}-V_{BE}}{I_b}$$ and it seems to be right.

These are the correct values according to the solution:

- \$R_1=322\text{ kΩ}\$
- \$R_2=2140\text{ Ω}\$

I can't seem to find out how to get \$R_2\$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the numbers you have, and *assuming* you want the collector to rest at 50% of the supply voltage. then Ohm's Law:

E = I x R

R = E / I

R2 = (Supply/2) / 0.005 A

R2 = 5 / .005

R2 = 1 K

Note that the circuit will not actually work.  Biasing the base with a single resistor is called dangle biasing, and is severely unstable.  The gain of the transistor changes with temperature, with changes in collector current, and from part to part.

Comment: why would you assume the collector should rest at 50% of the supply voltage, is that common scenario ? Also, the solution is not 1k but 2.14k. Any clues to that ?

Comment: Given the large lack of information from the OP, assumptions happen.  It is common for a linear amplifier to be biased to the power rails midpoint to maximize the available peak-to-peak voltage swing.  10 V Vcc and 5 mA Ic are stated, so the solution for the operating point I mentioned is 5 mA.  How did you get 2.14 K?  Note that 2.14 K is not an E96 standard value.

Comment: Ah, I see. 2.14k is just the stated correct solution, probably picked up from an exercise book. Anyway, I was trying to to use one such NPN transistor not in its active quadrant but at saturation. How would R2 be determined in that case ? Say, for 5V supply, my transistor can withstand 50V across the CE junctions; do I even need an R2 in this scenario ?

Comment: R2 limits the collector current to a max value at saturation.  Without it the transistor will attempt to dead short the power supply and fail.

Comment: Using Ohm's Law, the voltage drop across 2140 ohms at 5 mA is 10.7 V.  This is not possible in the circuit.

Comment: haha, good catch regarding Ohm's law! So then the collector current I_c is not  entirely dependent on the base current I_b ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  But the question has fixed conditions attached that directed a solution that is independent of the base current.  Note - that circuit is the worst possible way to design a 1-transistor linear amplifier.  The gain of a transistor is barely predictable and not stable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90526/discussion-between-kellogs-and-analogkid).

Comment: I was taught to NEVER use that simple circuit because a transistor part number has a wide range of current gain and you need some negative feedback to make many transistors work properly.